# How to use forAll method of Doctrine ArrayCollection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Can anybody show example of using `forAll` method of [Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#389-405)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. The class you linked to implements the `forAll` method in a following manner:

```
foreach ($this->_elements as $key => $element) {
     if ( ! $p($key, $element)) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

So, based on that you should invoke the `forAll` like:

```
$collection = ... #some data

$collection->forAll(function($key, $item){
    // Your logic here, based on $key and $item
});
```

Hope this help....

### EDIT (the example):

- You have an object of entity `Student`, which has a `OneToMany` to student's marks.
- You want to check if student has passed **all** the subjects he/she elected

  ```
  $student = ....
  $allPassed = $student->getMarks()->forAll(function($key, $mark){
      return $mark->getValue() != 'F';
  });
  ```

The `$allPassed` will hold `TRUE` if all marks were either 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'. Even if one of them were `F` if will be `FALSE`.

Comment: I can't understand how `$key` and `$element` parameters passed to the Closure, but now I understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to highlight that forAll method exits as soon as the inner function returns a *false*.

Following the example of Perovic, take for instance that the $student has 10 marks, where only one is an 'F'.

If the 'F' mark is the 10th element of the array, the function 
    `$mark->getValue()`
 will be invoked 10 times.
On the other hand, if the 'F' mark is the first element of the array, `$mark->getValue()` will be invoked only once, since the function immediately returns false, and forAll method stops evaluating.

Comment: The first sentence should actually be stated as  `returns a falsey value` Since it will exit when the value is `0, false, null, ""` Actual source can be seen in the accepted answer. Results: https://3v4l.org/4g6DJ So in effect the method can be thought of as `testAll()`